# How to fix this basic example of threading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I am trying to teach myself how to use threading in Python. I have come up with the basic problem of trying to interrupt a function that would continue printing the square of a number forever after only 10 seconds. I used this website as an example: http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/19/a-basic-example-of-threads-synchronization-in-python/. The code that I have now does not work as intended and I'm wondering if any of you could help me fix it so I can understand threading better. Thank you in advance!

```
import threading
import time

def square(x):
    while 1==1:
        time.sleep(5)
        y=x*x
        print y

def alarm():
    time.sleep(10)
    go_off.set()


def go():
    go_off= threading.Event()
    squaring_thread = threading.Thread(target=square, args = (go_off))
    squaring_thread.start()
    square(5)
go()
```

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=square, args = (go_off))`: you're passing a function where a number is expected to compute the square...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Could you explain what I should do instead? If I replace that with     threading.Thread(target=square(6), args = (go_off)) the program continues to print out 36 indefinitely without stopping.

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=square(6))` calls the routine outside the thread. That's a classic. See my answer.

Comment: To all those that might be able to answer, just to be clear, I'm trying to signal the program to stop printing out the square of a number.

Comment: `Threads  and Synchronization` ? Bullshit ... How will be sure value of `cpu_clock` ? Check my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import threading
import time
#Global scope to be shared across threads
go_off = threading.Event()

def square(x):
    while not go_off.isSet():
        time.sleep(1)
        print x*x

def alarm():
    time.sleep(10)
    go_off.set()


def go():
    squaring_thread = threading.Thread(target=square,args = (6,))
    alarm_thread = threading.Thread(target=alarm , args = ())
    alarm_thread.start()
    squaring_thread.start()
go()
```

Comment: The other option would be to pass the Event(go_off) as an argument to the function

Comment: Thank you so much! You are amazing!